# How to CreateTopic in Ceph as a user

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, ceph, radosgw

I'm trying to create a topic in Ceph so that I can receive notifications when an object is uploaded to a bucket.

When I call the CreateTopic endpoint without any AWS credentials (as an anonymous user), the call succeeds.

However, in order to receive notifications on a topic, the topic and bucket must have the same owner. So, I need to create the topic as an authenticated user with credentials. However, using a different service name for the AWS authorization header, I either get a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error or a `NotImplemented` error. I believe the `NotImplemented` error is inaccurate since the endpoint seems to be functioning when no credentials are passed.

How should I authorize this request to create a topic as a user?

I am using Insomnia REST client and Ceph 14.2.5.

[The parameters used for the CreateTopic request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsJGU.png)

[When the service is s3, results in a NotImplemented error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OUXj.png)

[When the service is sns (or any other string, including a blank string), results in a SignatureDoesNotMatch error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoIbP.png)

[When authentication is disabled, the request succeeds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/230mC.png)

Comment: AWS [provide documentation for correctly signing requests to their apis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was trying AWS V2 and V4 authentication, but you need to use V3 with this endpoint.

Someone on the mailing list pointed me to this example of how to do it with Python: https://github.com/ceph/ceph/blob/master/examples/boto3/topic_with_endpoint.py